# useState doesn't update my setState correctly in next.js

Tags: next.js, react-hooks

I have a few animations on my hero section with framer.motion that I want only on the first load.

I wanted to store someting in the local storage to track if yes or not I display the animations, working with a useState and useEffect.

The useEffect does affect the local storage as expected but then I'm not sure why my hero section still display the same thing as if useState didn't change.

```
    async function Hero() {

    const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('animate') != null){
             localStorage.setItem('animate', 'false')
             setAnimate(false)
          }else{
             localStorage.setItem('animate', 'true')
          }
        }
    }, []);

  return (
     <div>
     <motion.h1 animate={{opacity:1}} initial={animate == true ? {opacity:0} : {opacity:1}}>Some text</motion.h1>
     </div>
    )
}

export default Hero
```

On the first load 'animate' in the localStorage is true and then switch on false, but it doesn't affect the animation.

I checked with a simple piece of code to be sure it doesn't come from my framer code but it's the same

```
{animate == true?<h1>True</h1>:<h1>False</h1>}
```

I tried to change the dependancies array but still doesn't work.

with this code :

```
async function Hero() {

const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(true);
console.log(animate)

useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('animate') != null){
            localStorage.setItem('animate', 'false')
            setAnimate(false)
        }else{
            localStorage.setItem('animate', 'true')
        }
}, []);
```

It first logs true than when I navigate elsewhere and come back it logs true then infinite false (like 1000 times a second)

Any idea?

**Edit**

Here is the full code.
This component is insdide a components direcotry itself inside the app directory.
I don't know why but when I had a useEffect to the component it makes the whole page slow and even crash the window.

```
 'use client'
import {React, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { IoIosPin } from "react-icons/io";
import { IoMdBus } from "react-icons/io";
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

export default async function Hero() {

    const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('animate') != null){
             localStorage.setItem('animate', 'false')
             setAnimate(false)
          }else{
             localStorage.setItem('animate', 'true')
          }
        },[])


  return (
    <div className='px-2 pt-3 mdl:px-8 lgl:px-12 xl:px-16'>
        <div className='relative w-full bg-[url("/hero/cabinet-paysage.jpg")] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat sml:min-h-[300px] mdl:min-h-[400px] lg:min-h-[450px] lgl:min-h-[500px]'>
            <motion.div className="w-full h-full bg-bgwhite sml:min-h-[300px] mdl:min-h-[400px] lg:min-h-[450px] lgl:min-h-[500px]" animate={{opacity:1}} initial={animate == true ? {opacity:0} : {opacity:1}} transition={{ease: "linear", duration:0.5}}>
                <div className=' w-full h-full max-w-[1000px] sml:min-h-[300px] mdl:min-h-[400px] p-5 mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 grid-rows-8 auto-rows-fr auto-cols-fr sml:grid-cols-3 sml:grid-rows-2'>
                    <div className='row-span-4 flex flex-col justify-center gap-3 mdl:gap-4 lg:gap-5 xl:gap-6 sml:col-start-1 sml:col-end-3 sml:row-span-2 '>
                        <motion.h1 animate={{opacity:1}} initial={animate == true ? {opacity:0} : {opacity:1}} transition={{delay:0.2, ease: "linear", duration:0.3}}>Some text</motion.h1>
                        <motion.h2 animate={{opacity:1}} initial={animate == true ? {opacity:0} : {opacity:1}} transition={{delay:0.4, ease: "linear", duration:0.3}}>Some text</motion.h2>
                        <motion.p className='sml:max-w-[450px] headertext' animate={{opacity:1}} initial={animate == true ? {opacity:0} : {opacity:1}} transition={{delay:0.6, ease: "linear", duration:0.3}}>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte et</motion.p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row-span-3 flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2 sml:col-start-3 sml:row-span-2'>
                        <div className='flex justify-center gap-4'>
                            <motion.div className='flex flex-col items-center w-24 text-center' animate={{opacity:1}} initial={animate == true ? {opacity:0} : {opacity:1}} transition={{delay:0.2, ease: "linear", duration:0.3}}>
                                <IoIosPin className='reacticons'/>
                                <p className='headertext'>Some text</p>
                            </motion.div>
                            <motion.div className='flex flex-col items-center w-24 text-center' animate={{opacity:1}} initial={animate == true ? {opacity:0} : {opacity:1}} transition={{delay:0.4, ease: "linear", duration:0.3}}>
                                <IoMdBus className='reacticons'/>
                                <p className='headertext'>Some text</p>
                            </motion.div>
                        </div>
                        <Link href="/#contact" className='buttonheader inline-block text-center self-center'>
                            Prendre Rendez-Vous
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </motion.div>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing async from the function, because it won't work

````
function Hero() {

   const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(true);

   useEffect(() => {
       if(localStorage.getItem('animate') != null){
            localStorage.setItem('animate', 'false')
            setAnimate(false)
         }else{
            localStorage.setItem('animate', 'true')
         }
       }
   }, []);

 return (
    <div>
    <motion.h1 animate={{opacity:1}} initial={{opacity:animate?0:1}}>Some text</motion.h1>
    </div>
   )
}

export default Hero```
````

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, no it doesn't work but I don't think it comes from this part of the code as even {animate == true?<h1>True</h1>:<h1>False</h1>} instead of the framer part is always "True"

Comment: so it may be related to localstorage did you check that

Comment: Yes the localstorage gets updated as expected it's the useState part that doesn't work

Comment: try giving animate as dependency in useeEffct

Comment: It doesn't work either :/. But when I write console.log(animate) under the useState declaration it logs true then false when I come back on the page. And the false is logged again and again like 1000 times a second

Comment: if you don't mind can you share you full code of this animate section

Comment: Yes I added the code of the whole component at the end of the post!

Comment: hey could please try changing the name of variable like change localStorage.setItem('animate', 'false') to localStorage.setItem('animatedStyle', 'false') or likewise

Comment: AND ALSO remove the async part and give  export default function Hero() {

Comment: Thank you! I removed the async keyword and the useState now works fine! But there is a last problem, It looks like the page is first mounted with the default useState value then the useEffect fires and updates useState. But the component is already mounted with the inital value and the change in useState won't affect something like initial={{opacity:animate?0:1}}. If I write something like {animate?<p>True</p>:<p>False</p>} It will display True for 0.1sec then False. I'm not sure if I'm clear ^^

Comment: could you please like the answer